# Weighted $L_1$ norm

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

I try minimizing the following expression :

$
V(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - u|w_i
$

$w_i > 0 $

I need to find u that minimize this expression.
I know how to do it for w=1 (which is is the median). Any ideas for the general case ?

Comment: Do you assume that $w_i>0$ ?

Comment: yes I do.
I edited the original message. Thanks

Comment: Do you take a closer look at the weighted median?

Answer (score 1):

Try to plot $V(x)$ as function of $u$. Then you'll realize that minimum is attained at some $x_k$. So,
$$
\min_{u\in\mathbb{R}} V(x)
=\min_{k=1,\ldots,n}V(x_k)
=\min_{k=1,\ldots,n}\sum_{i=1}^n w_i|x_i-x_k|
$$